# Object has Faces but no Vertices

Tags: vertices, faces, select

I have an object that is made up of different pieces, its all under one object, but for some reason some of the pieces don't have vertices but they have faces? I want to know what caused it, and how I can get the vertices back.[image: Can select faces but not vertices]

Comment: Try looking at it in wireframe mode (SHIFT-Z) which should show you where the vertices are.

Comment: It cannot be all one object unless a modifier is affecting the geometry. Having faces but no vertices is impossible.

Comment: hard to say but from the gif it looks like you have the wrong object selected

Comment: It is impossible to have faces without vertices. Maybe the vertices are hidden by some object. Try going in wireframe mode or x - ray mode

Comment: I have the same issue with a window. . Did you figure it out? I can't even delete this shet. .

Answer (score -1):

I know it's an old question but the solution was that the origin of the object was not the world center for me so what i wanted to delete was the mirrored part of the object.

Somehow the object's origin shifted away.